# Using Grep in Unix to find dollar values from $10.00-$99.99

Tags: unix, escaping, grep

Trying to write the correct `grep` command to search a file for occurrences of any dollar values ranging from `$10.00` to `$99.99`.  My main concern is if the `$` symbol needs an escape `\`.  So far I have this

```
grep '$[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]' file
```

just wondering if it should be

```
grep '\$[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]' file
```

instead.

Comment: Well, you could have just tried it...

Comment: I need to use the unix machines at my school which is far away.  Also its -30degrees C outside...

Answer (score 1):

Both $ and . will need escape due to . being the greedy character matcher.

Comment: Matches anything, unlike \w matching only word characters, \d digits, etc.

Comment: In the context of regex, the word "greedy" usually refers to _qualifiers_, such as `+` and `*`.

Comment: @dardo that's not what greedy means. In regexp `.` matches any **single** character `\w` matches a **single** word characters and `\d` matches a **single** digits character. Greedy applies to quantifiers like `*` and `+` that will match the longest substring possible.

Comment: True, but you have to admit, . is the most "greedy" of matchers on characters specifically.  I didnt mean to necessarily use it in the context of greedy qualifier.